# QTableWidget selection rectangle does not disappear even after editing is finished

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I am implementing a QTableWidget, the selection rectangle seems not to be disappearing even after I finish editing and change my selection to other cells.
Below is a screenshot of the QTableWidget.

[image: Example]

Below is the code for constructing the tablewidget, rows are added dynamically via a QPushButton:

```
{
setObjectName(obj_name);
layout = new QVBoxLayout();

table = new QTableWidget(this);
table->verticalHeader()->setVisible(false);
table->verticalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(20);
table->setFixedWidth(180);
table->setColumnCount(3);
table->setColumnWidth(0,75);
table->setColumnWidth(1, 75);
table->setColumnWidth(2, 25);
QStringList header = { "Tag", "Threshold" ,""};
table->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(header);
table->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Fixed);

add = new QPushButton("+", this);
add->setObjectName("btn_threshold_add");

layout->addWidget(table);
layout->addWidget(add);
setLayout(layout);

connect(add, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(add_row()));
}
```

Below is the code for add_row() SLOT, triggers when user clicked the add button:

```
void TagThresholdWidget::add_row()
{
int row = table->rowCount();
QPushButton *del = new QPushButton("-", table);

table->insertRow(row);
table->setCellWidget(row, 2, del);

connect(del, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(remove_row()));
 }
```

Anyone has any clue to how to solve this problem? Its seems like a Qt graphical paint bug to me

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @drescherjm thanks for the comment, I have added my code

Comment: @Komgcn verifiable means you provide a code we can run on our side. What you provided has missing parts, and the problem might be there.

Comment: @UmNyobe it is a very huge project, these are basically the codes for this part(which is a custom QWidget named TagThresholdWidget), could you tell me what part of codes that are missing that you want me to provide?

Comment: @Komgcn Here nobody has asked you to publish your very huge project, we have asked you to publish a [mcve], if your project is small that could be the [mcve], but if it is big then create another project and implement the functionality that brings you problems, do not add unnecessary things. I recommend you read the link